# Django - Register App Model in Custom AdminSite

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a django project with three apps: website, blog, and customauth. The customauth app implements a custom user and AdminSite. The blog app has a Post model. I am trying to register the Post model with the custom AdminSite and I receive the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /my_admin/
Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'blog'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin\\/(?P<app_label>customauth)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_admin/
Django Version: 2.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'blog'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin\\/(?P<app_label>customauth)/$']
```

Here is customauth/admin.py:

```
class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    site_title = "Custom Administration Area"
    site_header = 'Custom Administration Area'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyAdminSite, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^my_view/$', self.my_view, name='my_view'),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self,request):
        value = "You're looking at the new admin view."
        context = dict(
           # Include common variables for rendering the admin template.
           self.each_context(request),
           # Anything else you want in the context...
           key=value,
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, "website/admin.html", context)

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin_site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
```

And here is blog/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin    
from customauth.admin import admin_site
# Register your models here.
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin_site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
```

Here is the website/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from customauth.admin import admin_site

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',       admin.site.urls,            name='admin'),
    path('my_admin/',    include('customauth.urls'), name='custom_admin'),
    path('',             views.index,                name='index'),
    path('latest_news/', include('blog.urls'),       name='latest_news')
]
```

And here is the customauth/urls.py:

```
from . import views
from .admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin_site.my_view, name='custom_admin'),
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had some troubles with that `NoReverseMatch` error when I copy-pasted from django docs. The line: `self.admin_site.each_context(request)` should be `self.each_context(request)` as you written. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I did wrong.

The problem is the way I configured the urls.

In website.urls I changed:

```
path('my_admin/',    include('customauth.urls'), name='custom_admin'),
```

to

```
path('my_admin/',    admin_site.urls,      name='custom_admin'),
```

And that solved the problem. I no longer need the customauth.urls file.